# "Косяк" функции each()?

Tags: php

Функция `each($array)` пропускает первый элемент массива и после последнего ещё раз проходит "вхолостую". Массив создаётся автоматически с различными строковыми ключами.

Если `$array ('title' => 'blabla', 'value' => 'blabla', 'sTitle' => 'blabla')`

```
each($array)
echo ' !ключ: '.key($array);
```

Получим на выходе:

```
!ключ: value !ключ: sTitle !ключ:
```

В чём дело? Как **правильно** решить проблему?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
foreach($array as $key=>$value){
  echo ' !ключ: '.$key' !значение: '.$value;
}
```

Comment: как прогнать - см выше.

Answer (score 2):

Явно путаница между `each` и `foreach`.

Надо либо так:

```
while (list($key, $val) = each($array)) {
    echo "$key => $val\n";
}
```

Либо вон как [@knes](/users/2825/knes) сказал. Но! функция `key()` не смещает указатель. Он смещен после первого «холостого» вызова `each`, соответственно, последний `each` уже вышел за пределы массива, и `key` возвращает пустое значение.

Comment: точно. Убираю про key:)